# php zend routes variable

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

## Zend_Route code problem

This code is working.

```
resources.router.routes.babynameslist.route               = "baby-names/baby-boy-names-list-from/:char
resources.router.routes.babynameslist.defaults.module     = "default"
resources.router.routes.babynameslist.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.babynameslist.defaults.action     = "babynameslist"
```

http://example.com/baby-names/baby-boy-names-list-from/a/

but I want to use this.

```
resources.router.routes.babynameslist.route               = "baby-names/baby-boy-names-list-from-:char/"
resources.router.routes.babynameslist.defaults.module     = "default"
resources.router.routes.babynameslist.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.babynameslist.defaults.action     = "babynameslist"
```

it's not working ( -:char/ )

http://example.com/baby-names/baby-boy-names-list-from-a/

pls help me how I can make "baby-boy-names-list-from-a"

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass the "a" to a variable and adapt you're script in consiquence.
I'm not sure, but i think that dynamic route are not working in Zend_Route.

For example :

```
http://example.com/baby-names/baby-boy-names-list-from/a
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using a `Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex`.
Define it as below:

```
resources.router.routes.babynameslist.type                = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
resources.router.routes.babynameslist.route               = "baby-names/baby-boy-names-list-from-(\w)/"
resources.router.routes.babynameslist.map.1               = "char"
resources.router.routes.babynameslist.defaults.module     = "default"
resources.router.routes.babynameslist.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.babynameslist.defaults.action     = "babynameslist"
```